# Concatenate two atoms in prolog without using atom_concat

Tags: prolog

I want to write prolog that can essentially do what this is doing

```
atom_concat('3',' =',Answer).
Answer = '3 ='.
```

But I do not want to use the atom_concat function (or any built in predicates). I would also like the answer to have no quotation marks in it.

I have tried implementing a method that operates the same as the append method, which I have called merge.

```
merge([],Xs,Xs).
merge([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]):-
    merge(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

But when I write this into my db.pl file I get false when running it.

```
?- [db].
true.

?- merge('3',' =',Answer).
false.
```

Comment: It fails because an atom does not unify with a list. You would need `atom_chars/2` or something similar for that. Why can't you use it?

Comment: It's for a school assignment. I'm building a compiler interpreter with prolog and I am just not allowed to use built in predicates in my solution. What exactly should I do with atom_chars/2?

Comment: `concat_atoms(Atom1, Atom2, Atom3) :- atom_chars(Atom1, C1), atom_chars(Atom2, C2), merge(C1, C2, C3), atom_chars(Atom3, C3).`

Comment: Thank-you, do you know how I could get rid of the quotation marks? Also, this answer uses more built-in predicates, do you know how to implement this answer without them?

Comment: It only uses one built-in: `atom_chars/2`. `atom_chars/2` is implemented in C in the SWI Prolog library.

Comment: Yes I want to use no built-in's.

Comment: You won't be able to concatenate atoms without using a built-in, or writing your own C program to link with your Prolog program. Sounds like you have a larger problem you're trying to solve which you've boiled down to atom concatenation. You'll need to refactor that solution so that it doesn't require atom concatenation.

Comment: I can't recognize this: `merge('3',' =',Answer).` you've passed the arguments of __atom type__ in `merge/3` when __list type__ is expected there. it could be working in a such way: `name(atom, char_code_list)` though it's a built-in predicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
built_equality_structure(Id,Value,Id = Value).
```

If you call it with

```
?- built_equality_structure(a,3,X).
```

you will get the result

```
X = (a=3)
```

where the Prolog system only add parentheses for readability.

Comment: Ah yes, you've now created a new Complex Term from what I can tell, consisting of the unsolved question "Can atom 'a' unify with 3?" No, it can't, but it's not evaluated at this point so it's put in parentheses, meaning it's a separate problem. You are also missing the spacings you asked for in the original question, and the end result isn't a string or an atom, but a question in the form of a complex term that will always return false when evaluated. You're effectively asking is 1 equal to 2. For what purpose? I'm curious now.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you want to link string atom 'a' to numerical atom 3, the most sensible way to create that fact is to say a(3). You can then ask a(X) and the answer is X = 3, or a(3) which will return true.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mutate immutable values. You could use string_concat/3 to create a merger of two string atoms. By putting 'Variable' you are signalling Prolog that you want an ATOM called Variable. So numerical 3 and string atom '3' are not the same. What basically happens is you have two >immutables<, so a third has to be made that is an amalgamation of the other two.

[atom_concat](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom_concat/3)

[string_concat](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=string_concat/3)

'merge' is also a deprecated method, just to clear up any confusion:
  [merge](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=backward_compatibility%3Amerge/3)

The program you want:

The query

```
?- trace, (concat_strings(['Hello ','Hello ','Hello '],[world1,world2,world3],Output)).
```

The code

```
concat_strings([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[H3|T3]) :-
    string_concat(H1, H2, H3),
    concat_strings(T1,T2,T3).
concat_strings([],[],[]).
```

It takes the the first word of both lists, makes a new immutable atom from the 2 through string_concat and puts it in H3, which is then put onto the head of the list when the call ends. We have the end condition concat_strings([],[],[]) and the first 2 are the lists YOU pass, the third means T3 eventually unifies as T3 = [], which is also the atom to show Prolog the end of a list has been reached. Prolog then starts stepping back, adds [] as the tail and then adds the new atoms to the new list as it works its way back to your call.

OPINION:
My favorite resource for Prolog basics explained: http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=top